# Error delivering message to node:undefined [undefined]

Tags: javascript, node-red

After updating a flows in my Node-RED project by re-importing them, I encountered the following error:

```
12 Feb 13:42:43 - [error] Error delivering message to node:undefined [undefined]
12 Feb 13:42:43 - [error] TypeError: sendEvent.destination.node.receive is not a function
at deliverMessageToDestination (C:\METIER\fespnew\node_modules\@node-red\runtime\lib\flows\Flow.js:799:40)
at Immediate._onImmediate (C:\METIER\fespnew\node_modules\@node-red\runtime\lib\flows\Flow.js:815:21)
at processImmediate (node:internal/timers:476:21)
```

I couldn't find any documentation on this error, and it's proving difficult to understand what's happening. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the problem is related to a subflow. The workaround I discovered involves locating and deleting the problematic subflow, then recreating it.

Here's the step-by-step process:

1. delete the malfunctioning subflow from your Node-RED project
2. create a new subflow
3. import all nodes individually from the original subflow
4. re-establish connections with the Input, Output, and Status nodes of the subflow
5. change options and rename the subflow as necessary